# Need assistance with writing a SQL query

Tags: sql

Please somebody can help me write a SQL query. I don't know it, but I just need it for a quick fix.

I was trying something like this :

```
select college.colg_id,  
       college.student_id, 
       student.student_name from college,
       student     
       where college.student_id=student.student_id;
```

which gives me all data which I am not sure.

```
colg_id student_id
1           1
1           2
1           3
1           4
2           5
2           6

student_id  student_name
1            a1
2            b1
3            c1
4            d1
5            e1
6            f1
```

I just need data in form of

```
colg_id | student_id | student_name.
```

Comment: I want to help but please format your question a bit ... i cant understand what you want to achieve..

Comment: is it clear now.... i copied it from excel. i dont know how it came in one row. if i put my question in simple words i just want to add student_name in output of college table. where each name is displayed with their respective student_id

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c.colg_id, c.student_id, s.student_name FROM college c
LEFT JOIN student s ON s.student_id = c.student_id
```